# Show/Hide Div Based on Data Attribute

Tags: jquery

I would like to show/hide a div using a data attribute instead of a value. In this example  http://jsfiddle.net/copperlocks/nebY8/8/, how would I go about doing that in the jQuery?

```
<select id="test" name="test">
    <option value="" data-id="">Select</option>
    <option value="1" data-id="a">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-id="b">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-id="c">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-id="d">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5" data-id="e">Option 5</option>
</select>

<div id="something">Show Something</div>
```

For a value ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields();
    $("#test").change(function () {
        toggleFields(); });
});

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#test").val() > 2) $("#something").show();
    else $("#something").hide();
}
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work ...

```
if ($("#test").data('id') == "a") 

if ($("#test").attr('data-id') =="a")
```

I'm new to this and would appreciate your help :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data attribute is attached to the option, so checking the selected option would be the way to go

```
if ($("#test option:selected").data('id')  == "a" )
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nebY8/9/)

Comment: If you are dynamically creating/changing the html you should use .attr('data-id') to select the value as .data is cached on page creation with subsequent reads using cached data.

Comment: Please show how to use [`toggle(Boolean)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of `if`/`else`